# Vue.js Can't emit event to $root element

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm trying to $emit event to root, but it's not working. When I press enter it should emit to root and component should get that event and execute function which will push it to array.

**JS:**

```
Vue.component('input-comp',{
  template : `
       <div>
        <input type="text" v-model ="textData" v-on:keyup.enter ="pushMessages"/>
        <button v-on:click="pushMessages">Send text</button>
       </div>`,
  data : function(){
     return {
         textData : 'test Message'
     }
  },
  methods : {
    pushMessages : function(){
      this.$root.$emit('message', { message: this.textData })
    }
  }
})

var vm =  new Vue({
    el : '#parent',
    data : {
      msgs : []
    },
    methods : {
      pushMessages : function(payload){
          this.msgs.push(payload.message)
      }
    },
  updated(){
    this.$root.$on('message', this.pushMessages)
  }
})
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="parent">
  <p v-for="msg in msgs">{{msg}}</p>
  <input-comp></input-comp>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recommend to emit the event without $root as follows :

```
 methods : {
    pushMessages : function(){
        this.$emit('message', { message: this.textData })
    }
  }
```

and in parent component handle it like :

```
      <input-comp @message="pushMessages"></input-comp>
```

or try to use `mounted` hook instead of `updated` :

```
  mounted(){
     this.$root.$on('message', this.pushMessages)
    }
```

Comment: Yee, but i need to use $root. What if I will have more nested coponents